# Does thrust depends on rocket chamber shape?

Tags: rockets

i mark with green part of rocket which produce forward thrust and with red backward thrust.
integration of pressure around rocket walls gives total thrust,which allways act in forward direction..

Does thrust depends of rocket chamber shape and what is optimum shape to get max thrust?

[image]

Comment: This shouldn't have been migrated because [now it's here twice](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45336/23726).