# Contraction Ratio Impact on Performance for Liquid Rocket Engine

Tags: rockets, engine-design

How does one go about calculating the necessary contraction ratio (combustion chamber/nozzle throat cross sectional areas) of an engine with these parameters known...

- thrust
- nozzle throat area
- mass flow rate
- chamber pressure
- chamber temperature
- ratio of specific heats

Also, how does contraction ratio effect efficiency and performance?

Comment: is this a blueprint?

Comment: Contraction ratio does not, on its own, have any dramatic effects on a rocket's performance.  The throat size is, of course, very important, but not so much the two together.  Instead the contraction ratio may give some indication of 'characteristic length' which basically determines mixing effectiveness and C* efficiency.  

Please see if this question/answer helps you:
https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/45336/does-thrust-depend-on-rocket-chamber-shape/45344#45344