# How can I determine characteristic length (L*) of a rocket engine combustion chamber if there is little to no data collected on a similar engine?

Tags: rockets, combustion, combustion-chamber

I am designing a liquid bi-propellant rocket engine using Nitrous Oxide and Isopropyl Alcohol. I have all the necessary parameters for nozzle design and am at the stage of determining the combustion chamber’s L* (characteristic length). I know it’s a heavily empirical design parameter but the research done on N2O + IPA combustion is very niche. How should I go about determining it’s L* for the combustion chamber configuration design?

Comment: sorry, engine design is off-topic here.  The community has decided we don't want the potential accidents on our consciences.

Comment: This is a good question, but I am really sorry to have to say that this site is mainly for questions about space exploration and even though this question is related, we have made the decision not to answer questions about rocket engine design because we do not want anybody to have a serious accident because of us.

Comment: Questions about "engine design" are very much not off topic, there are hundreds of good ones here. Questions about physically building your own amateur engine are off topic here.

Comment: Check this answer (https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/45336/does-thrust-depend-on-rocket-chamber-shape/45344#45344) 
or table 1 in this link (http://www.braeunig.us/space/propuls.htm). The specific propellant combination is not listed in the table, but you would be safe with similar values. Or very safe with larger values.